# Error while building OpenCV examples on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, ubuntu-10.10

I've used this tutorial to build OpenCV on ubuntu.
Everything goes well until I try to build the examples. when I do this:

> sh build_all.sh

many of the same error occurs:

> compiling tree_engine.cpp
>
> /usr/bin/ld:
> warning: libavutil.so.49, needed by
> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so,
> not found (try using -rpath or
> -rpath-link)

for each example the same error occurs.
The code compiles but trying to run the compiled code will fail with error:

> ./tree_engine: error while loading
> shared libraries: libavutil.so.49:
> cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory

I have no idea what this libavutil is.

I use ubuntu 10.10

Comment: So thanks to SIFE, I know the problem was different versions of libavutil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have it in different name, so try this:

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so*
```

In my case:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     20 Jan 17 00:30 /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so -> libavutil.so.50.15.1
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     20 Jan 17 00:30 /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.1 -> libavutil.so.50.15.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  54352 Jan 17 00:30 /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.50.15.1
```

As root type this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.50.15.1 /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.49
```

If you don't have this library, you can install via package manager:

```
apt-get install libavutil49
```

Comment: I have libavutil50 installed (I installed it with synaptic). but when I try "ls -l /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so*" I get nothing back

Comment: Try `ls -l /usr/lib/libavutil.so*`.

Comment: I have this same error using OpenCV with Python 2.6. When I tried to soft link libavutil.so.50 to libavutil.so.49, I get this error from Python: 

    import cv;
    ImportError: /usr/lib/libavutil.so.49: version `LIBAVUTIL_49' not found (required by /home/ely/OpenCV-2.2.0/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.2)

Any ideas? ALSO: the apt-get suggestion for libavutil49 does not work. apt-get says that packaged is obsoleted, at least from Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: FYI: Figured this out. Needed to go to the packages.ubuntu.com site for Lucid, manually download the libavutil49 package and install with dpkg. Then things go back to normal.